# SignalR and WebAPI

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to send notifications to web page, which is a client `WebAPI`.
So, I have 2 solutions, `Asp.Net MVC` application and `WebAPI` application. I have added `SignalR` `nuget` to both. `WebAPI` part has the following code:

```
public class ProgressHub : Hub
{
    public void Notification(string message)
    {
        Clients.Caller.onProgressNotification(message);
    }
}


private void SendMessage(string message)
{
    var context = Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
        .GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Hubs.ProgressHub>();
    context.Clients.All.onProgressNotification(message);
}
```

and then call it from my controller Action:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ZonalPost()
{
    SendMessage("Start");
    // my long operation
    SendMessage("Scan complete");
    // my long operation
    SendMessage("Convert complete");
    // my long operation
```

And in my web application (client part):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var progress = $.connection.progressHub;

        progress.client.onProgressNotification = function (message) {
            console.log(message);
        };
    });
```

but I got an error

> 430 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined

Why and how to solve?

Comment: Try to add `[HubName("progressHub")]` to your hub

Comment: how can it solve problem on client part?

Comment: Maybe it not recognized the hub

Comment: server part even can't be started at that time... or not?

Comment: Have you tried this? <script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

Comment: yes. But client and server parts of signalR - different solutions

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use something like the following:

```
$(function () {
    $.connection.hub.url = '<yourbackendurl>';
    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    var progress = connection.createHubProxy('progressHub');
    progress.on('onProgressNotification', function(message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
    connection.start()
        .done(function(){ console.log('Now connected, connection ID=' + connection.id); })
        .fail(function(){ console.log('Could not connect'); });
});
```

See the docs on [using SignalR without the generated proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client). Note that you also need to specify the server URL if you're connecting to a different server.